# View will get twice at onItemClick

Tags: android, listview

I am trying to change the background color by a click on ListView. My code looks like this:

```
@Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {          
        arg1.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
    }
```

The strange thing is this, if I click on Item number 7, the background of Item 7 changes but also from Item number 6.

Comment: Please have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/a/6923513/1321873

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its because ListView ***recycles*** the views (row items) used inside. The best solution would be to change background color of your desired row/item by overriding **`getView`** method in your adapter. By this, you'll have more control over your list items and you may reset the background color for other unwanted views. For more info, read [this](http://lucasr.org/2012/04/05/performance-tips-for-androids-listview/)