# Checkbox in ListView with odd checking behaviour

Tags: java, android, android-listview, android-checkbox

I am new to Java and Andriod development.

I have a view within my app which contains a ListView

I then have a custom Adapter which inherits from an ArrayAdapter

within the view in the getView method I return a row which contains some text and a checkbox

now so far this all works great my list is populated and I can check my items, and all the events seem to fire as expected.

My problem that I am having is that I check the first 3 items and then I notice that the 11th, 12th and 13th items are checked and as I scroll I see that at regular intervals other checkboxes also seem to be checked in the same pattern.

If I check about 10 checkboxes then it will end up checking all the items in the list of about 80...

can anyone explain what I have done wrong?

I dont think any code will help explain this as I do not set the checkstate of the checkbox anywhere, this is all handled itself, so the fact items are being checked is puzzling me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: anything that is not clear please ask and I will respond to the best of my ability :D

Comment: If you put the code of your getView method I can tell you exactly where happens the issue ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is happening because Android recycles list items for performance purposes, here you have the solution of this problem:
[ListView reusing views when ... I don't want it to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6921462/listview-reusing-views-when-i-dont-want-it-to)

Hope to help :)

Comment: thanks very much will check it out and then mark as appropriate :)

Answer (score 1):

This is expected behavior. ListView reuses views in the adapter.
So what you want is to keep a `Set` of "selected items" and add an item or remove it when the `CheckBox` is clicked and then in your getView add the following code:

```
if(mSelected.contains(getItem(position)) {
    checkBox.setChecked(true);
} else {
    checkBox.setChecked(false);
}
```

This way when the row is reused the `CheckBox` will be the proper status.