# Inflating to many views in a list

Tags: android, listview, reference, inflate

I have a listView and want to expand each item when you press it. I have the following code to do so. I works by inflating a ViewStub.

It works fine. That is, when I press a list item it does indeed inflate. So far so good.

However, my list is long, and I noticed that when I scroll down the list other items have inflated as well. I'm not entirely sure why. And when I scroll up again the item I originally press has "deflated" and some other item has become inflated instead.

```
@override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {


    ListView list = getListView();
    int start = list.getFirstVisiblePosition();
    for (int i = start, j = list.getLastVisiblePosition(); i <= j; i++) {
        Cursor item = (Cursor) list.getItemAtPosition(i);

        if (id == item.getLong(item.getColumnIndex(ItemColumns._ID))) {
            View view = list.getChildAt(i - start);

            ViewStub stub = (ViewStub) view.findViewById(R.id.stub);
            if (stub != null) {
                stub.inflate();

            }       
        }
    }
}
```

Any help will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Android reuses views in a `ListView`. That is why there is a `convertView` in the `getView(..)` method of your `Adapter`. This SO post will explain: [ListView reusing views when ... I don't want it to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6921462/listview-reusing-views-when-i-dont-want-it-to)
Basically what you need to do is hold a `Set` of items that are currently expanded, and in your `getView(..)` method do a lookup:

```
if(mExpanded.contains(getItem(position))) {
  //show expansion
} else {
  //hide expansion
}
```

then in your `onListItemClick` method you want to add the following:

```
if(!mExpanded.remove(getListView().getItem(position))) {
   mExpanded.add(getListView().getItem(position));
}
```

This will cause it to attempt remove the item, if the `Set` is not changed - that is the item wasn't in the `Set` to be removed then you want to add it...