# After scrolling listView Items View elements mixed with

Tags: java, android

I have simple ԼistView in android project .Of ListView Items  are two type.
1. Song Type
2. Folder Type
ListView  items model 'SongModel', there are TYPE field
SongModel

```
public class SongModel {


public String title;
public int type;

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}
public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public int getType() {
    return type;
}
public void setType(int type) {
    this.type = type;
}
```

}

Of ListView  items View I have 3 elements :TextView for song name,ImageView for song or folder photo,and ImageButton for song play.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/song_photo"
    android:layout_width="119dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />



    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView" />


</LinearLayout>

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/add_queue"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="542dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
```

In Adapter class I check,if TYPE=1 I in items View paint song photo.And if TYPE=2 I paint folder photo,I  ImageButton Visibility set View.GONE.

```
package com.example.adapter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

  public class SongAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<SongModel> {
private ArrayList<SongModel> entries;
private Activity activity;

 static class ViewHolder {

  public ImageButton song_play;
  public TextView song_name;
  public ImageView song_photo;


 }
  public SongAdapter(Activity a, int textViewResourceId,ArrayList<SongModel> entries) {

  super(a, textViewResourceId, entries);
    this.entries = entries;
    this.activity = a;
}


 @Override
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
  View rowView = convertView;
  if (rowView == null) {
  LayoutInflater inflater = activity.getLayoutInflater();
  rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
  ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
  viewHolder.song_name = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.title);
  viewHolder.song_photo = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.song_photo);
  viewHolder.song_play = (ImageView) rowView .findViewById(R.id.song_play);
  rowView.setTag(viewHolder);
}

ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) rowView.getTag();
SongModel song = entries.get(position);

 holder.song_name.setText(song. getTitle());

if (song.getType()==2)
{ 

  holder.song_play.setVisibility(View.Gone);
  holder.song_photo.setImageResource(R.drawable.folder);

}
else
{
     holder.song_photo.setImageResource(R.drawable.song);
}
 rowView.setTag(getItemViewType(position));
 return rowView;
}
  }
```

in Activity code

```
 package com.example.adapter;

 import java.util.ArrayList;

 import org.json.JSONArray;
 import org.json.JSONException;
 import org.json.JSONObject;

 import android.os.Bundle;
  import android.app.Activity;
   import android.view.Menu;
   import android.widget.ListView;

 public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private ArrayList<SongModel> fetch;
private ListView MusicItemlistView;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    MusicItemlistView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listview);
     fetch = new ArrayList<SongModel>();

    try {
        JSONObject jsonData=new JSONObject(datajson);
    JSONArray dataArray=jsonData.getJSONArray("responseBody");
    SongModel sg;
    JSONObject js;
    for(int i=0;i<dataArray.length();i++)
    {
        sg=new SongModel();
        js=(JSONObject) dataArray.get(i);
        sg.setAlbum(js.getString("artist"));
        sg.setFileName(js.getString("fileName"));
        sg.setType(Integer.parseInt(js.getString("type")));
        sg.setDuration(Integer.parseInt(js.getString("duration")));
        fetch.add(sg);
    }
    MyPerformanceArrayAdapter  adapter = new MyPerformanceArrayAdapter        (this,R.id.listview, fetch);
    MusicItemlistView.setAdapter(adapter);
} catch (JSONException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

 }
```

When starting application,work all right,all Items painting true,If folder no ImageButton,If song There are ImageButton.

[image]

After scrolling listView Items View elements mixed with,folder item adding ImageButton,and  song Items no ImageButton.

[image]

Please help me,for correct error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TRY this :

```
if (song.getType()==2)
{ 

  holder.song_play.setVisibility(View.Gone);
  holder.song_photo.setImageResource(R.drawable.folder);

}
else
{
 holder.song_play.setVisibility(View.VISISBLE);
 holder.song_photo.setImageResource(R.drawable.song);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you set visibility of `song_play` to `View.Visible` when song type is not 2. Your cells get reused and some reused views have song_play elements invisible.

```
if (song.getType()==2)
{ 

  holder.song_play.setVisibility(View.Gone);
  holder.song_photo.setImageResource(R.drawable.folder);

}
else
{
     holder.song_play.setVisibility(View.Visible); //Add this here.
     holder.song_photo.setImageResource(R.drawable.song);
}
```

Comment: But those case song_play photo  always will be ISVisiblity

Comment: I used `View.Gone` in else earlier. Corrected it now to View.Visible.

Comment: You have to explicitly set the Visibility or InVisibility of elements in each and every cell. In your case the cells are reused and song_play elements visibility is controlled in cells else where. Reusing of views in `ListView` is explained here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6921462/listview-reusing-views-when-i-dont-want-it-to

Comment: Thank you very much,for link