# Not able to set headers in a Listview using a SimpleAdapter in Android

Tags: android, listview, header, simpleadapter

I am trying to group my `ListView` items using a `SimpleAdapter`. I am using two `Layouts` , r1 and r2. I have done the following coding, but I am getting only the contents of layout `r2` displayed in my ListView. Can anyone guide me where I am going wrong? My codes are as below:

```
 adapter=new SimpleAdapter(MainActivity.this, arraylist,R.layout.r1,new String[]{"key1","key2"},new int[]{R.id.textView1,R.id.textView2})
    {



        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            View v=super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(MainActivity.this.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                int type = getItemViewType(position);
                Log.i("position + convertview + type ",""+position+","+convertView+","+type);
                if(convertView==null)
                {

                     v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.r2, parent, false);
                }
                else
                {
                     v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.r1, parent, false);
                }



                return v;

        }

    };

    l.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: I think you have to create your custom adapter with getViewtype() implementation.

Comment: Check out this : http://android.amberfog.com/?p=296

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `getView` have

```
 if (type == FIRST_TYPE) {
       //infalte layout of type1
 }else if( type == SECOND_TYPE){
      //infalte layout of type2
 }
```

Your type corresponds to.

```
private static final int FIRST_TYPE= 0;
private static final int SECOND_TYPE = 1;
```

You can have the header based on the position.

```
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {

    if (position== 0){
        type = FIRST_TYPE;
    } else if  (position == 1){
        type = SECOND_TYPE;
    }
    return type;
}
```

You could also use commonsware merge adapter

https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-merge

Comment: What is FIRST_TYPE and SECOND_TYPE here?

Comment: @Ann 0 corrsponds to header and 1 corresponds to the content. Its upto you to modify

Comment: I am not able to override getItemViewType

Comment: @Ann use ArrayAdapter or BaseAdapter

Answer (score 0):

Judging condition is wrong

convertView aways be null.

you can search `android ListView resusing views`
e.g [ListView reusing views when ... I don't want it to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6921462/listview-reusing-views-when-i-dont-want-it-to)

so if you want use two layout, use other Judging condition.