# Force adapter not to use already inflated/used layouts

Tags: android

How to force adapter not use/repeat already inflated layouts, if the screen room is not enough to display all the items in listview, gridview or expandablelistview.

I have problem in expandablelistview, if I set background color of the selected item, another item`s background color is also changed(at first this item is not displayed on the screen, it appears after scroll).

So I conclude that second item is the same as the first.

Comment: The whole Idea of a listView / Recyclerview is to do exactly this ..

Comment: possible duplicate of [ListView reusing views when ... I don't want it to](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6921462/listview-reusing-views-when-i-dont-want-it-to)

Answer (score 1):

In your adapter you should set the default background for all the items.
And change this background only for the item(s) wanted.

something like:

```
holder.background.setBackground(defaultColor);
if (needTochange){
  holder.background.setBackground(newColor);
}
```

Comment: Hi Chol, the main I am using is the same as yours. But since the views(holders) are repeated, below view(holder) background is also changing

Comment: Is the needtoChange boolean is depending of the position?

Comment: it depends on clicked child.I am changing the clicked child background color, on the OnChildClick event

Comment: Can you show your OnChildCLick event implementation? I think the needToChange needs to be related to the list position in the adapter