# Android ListView with toggle button

Tags: android, listview, android-togglebutton

I'm having a problem when my ListView has more itens that can appear on the screen; in other words, when it gets scroll. The problem is, when I click in one of the toggle buttons, it's change the visibility of the ImageView. However, when I click on it, it is changing the visibility of more than the respective clicked.

I'm using an adapter to display the list itens.

I added the code below:

```
public class CriteriosAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Criterio> {

private Context context;

public CriteriosAdapter(Context context, List<Criterio> objects) {
    super(context, 0, objects);
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final Criterio criterio = getItem(position);
    final CriterioViewHolder viewHolder;

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.fragment_row, parent, false);

        viewHolder = new CriterioViewHolder();
        viewHolder.txtCriterio = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtCriterio);
        viewHolder.tgIrregular = (ToggleButton)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tgIrregular);
        viewHolder.btnCam = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btnCam);

        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    }
    else {
        viewHolder = (CriterioViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
    }

    viewHolder.txtCriterio.setText(criterio.nome);
    viewHolder.txtCriterio.setTextColor(context.getColor(R.color.white));
    viewHolder.tgIrregular.setChecked(false);

    viewHolder.tgIrregular.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (viewHolder.tgIrregular.isChecked()) {
                viewHolder.btnCam.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else {
                viewHolder.btnCam.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
        }
    });

    viewHolder.btnCam.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            FragmentActivity activity = (FragmentActivity)(context);
            android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fm = activity.getSupportFragmentManager();
            FotosFragment alertDialog = new FotosFragment();
            alertDialog.show(fm, "fragment_alert");
        }
    });

    return convertView;
}

class CriterioViewHolder {

    TextView txtCriterio;
    ToggleButton tgIrregular;

    ImageView btnCam;

}

}
```

Could someone help me with it?

Thank you.

**EDIT**

I added everything as you describe. However, I use that adapter in 5 fragments, if I go to another, and come back or scroll the list, it still lost the value.

I used criterio.getHash, because it is unique for all. And position, can repeat in other fragment, and make it weird.

```
public class CriteriosAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Criterio> {

private Context context;
public static Map<String, Criterio> irregularidades = new HashMap<String, Criterio>();
HashMap<String, Boolean> toggleButtonStateTracker = new HashMap<>();

public CriteriosAdapter(Context context, List<Criterio> objects) {
    super(context, 0, objects);
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final Criterio criterio = getItem(position);
    final CriterioViewHolder viewHolder;

    if (!toggleButtonStateTracker.containsKey(criterio.getHash())){
        toggleButtonStateTracker.put(criterio.getHash(),false);
    }

    Log.e("Toggle Track:", toggleButtonStateTracker.toString());

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.fragment_row, parent, false);

        viewHolder = new CriterioViewHolder();
        viewHolder.txtCriterio = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtCriterio);
        viewHolder.tgIrregular = (ToggleButton)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tgIrregular);
        viewHolder.btnCam = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btnCam);

        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    }
    else {
        viewHolder = (CriterioViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
    }

    viewHolder.txtCriterio.setText(criterio.nome);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        viewHolder.txtCriterio.setTextColor(context.getColor(R.color.white));
    } else {
        viewHolder.txtCriterio.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
    }

    viewHolder.tgIrregular.setId(criterio.id);

    final boolean isChecked = toggleButtonStateTracker.get(criterio.getHash());
    viewHolder.tgIrregular.setChecked(isChecked);

    viewHolder.btnCam.setTag(criterio.hash);

    if (isChecked) {
        viewHolder.btnCam.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        viewHolder.btnCam.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }

    viewHolder.tgIrregular.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            toggleButtonStateTracker.put(criterio.getHash(), isChecked);
            if (isChecked) {
                viewHolder.btnCam.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                irregularidades.put(criterio.getHash(), criterio);
            } else {
                viewHolder.btnCam.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                irregularidades.remove(criterio.getHash());
            }
        }
    });

    viewHolder.btnCam.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            FragmentActivity activity = (FragmentActivity) (context);
            android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fm = activity.getSupportFragmentManager();
            FotosFragment alertDialog = new FotosFragment();

            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putString("criterioTag", criterio.getHash());
            alertDialog.setArguments(args);

            alertDialog.setCancelable(false);
            alertDialog.show(fm, "fragment_alert");
        }
    });

    return convertView;
}

class CriterioViewHolder {

    TextView txtCriterio;
    ToggleButton tgIrregular;
    ImageView btnCam;

}

}
```

Comment: it's easier for people to help you if they have some [piece of code](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to work on - please show us what you have tried so far

Comment: Possible Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6921462/listview-reusing-views-when-i-dont-want-it-to  show us your adapter code, I'm pretty sure it's a problem due to the recycling of list items

Comment: @Desdroid, I added it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is due to the recycling of Views in `ListView` (and `RecyclerView`) The following happens to you:

1. You set visibility of an `ImageView` in one row to invisible with your `ToggleButton`
2. Your row gets scrolled out of sight and therefore gets recycled.
3. The recycled view still has an `ImageView` with visilibility set to `View.INVISIBLE`
4. You assign your new values to the row but don't change the visibility

To solve this you should have a `List`, `HashMap` or anything similar and track which `ToggleButton` is checked and which `ImageView` is visible. (You can do that with the position)

Then in your `public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)` method you check if this posision's (rows) image should be visible or not and set it accordingly with `viewHolder.btnCam.setVisibility()` and the `ToggleButton` as well.

### EDIT

Add this member variable to your adapter
`HashMap<Integer,Boolean> toggleButtonStateTracker = new HashMap<>;`

In your getView add this

```
if (! toggleButtonStateTracker.containsKey(position)){
  // Now the HashMap definitely contains the key
  toggleButtonStateTracker.put(position,false);
}

boolean isChecked = toggleButtonStateTracker.get(position);
viewHolder.tgIrregular.setChecked(isChecked);
if (isChecked){
  // if your toggle Button is checked, the btnCam should be invisible 
  viewHolder.btnCam.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
} else {
  viewHolder.btnCam.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

And finally add this tgIrregular

```
viewHolder.tgIrregular.setOnCheckedChangedListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
  @Override
  public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
    toggleButtonStateTracker.put(getAdapterPosition, isChecked);
  }
});
```

Comment: I understood, but I couldn't achieve that

Comment: Have a look at my edit. It's simple as that, just as I described. Next time elaborate what you weren't able to achieve / where your problem is. I'm not gonna to write your App for you.

Comment: I tried that, but it didn't work as I'm using an old version of support library. So, I tried to change getAdapterPosition to getPosition, but without success.

Comment: Again, show what your code currently looks like and describe what is not working / where your error is. Then I am better able to help.

Comment: I put an EDIT to show the new code, and I think, I describe the problem.

Comment: I think the problem is here : public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked)

Comment: Thank you! I find a topic that explain that Android has kind of bug that automatic call onCheckedChanged. Based on it, they inform that need to add: if(buttonView.isPressed())

Comment: Oh, sorry - didn't know about that. So your problem is solved?

Comment: Yes, and I appreciate your time! =D