# Why automatically a button gets selected for another position when scrolled in Recycler View

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am using recycler view to show a list which contains 12 items. 3 to 4 items will be viewable at once. I have show more button in each card row. If I click show more button of first card row, when I scroll down show more button of another card row will be selected automatically. Why will this happen and how can I fix this.

Below is the code of how am I setting the adapter:

```
ToadlineAdapter toadlineAdapter = new ToadlineAdapter(mContext, getData1());
 recyclerView.setAdapter(toadlineAdapter);
 toadlineAdapter.setClickListener(this);
 recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
```

My Adapter Code:

```
public class ToadlineAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ToadlineAdapter.MyViewHolder> implements ToadlineCommentAdapter.ClickListener {

    private ClickListener clickListener;
    private SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener clickListener1;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    Context mContext;
    List<TimelineDataStore> data = Collections.EMPTY_LIST;
    public ToadlineAdapter(Context context, List<TimelineDataStore> data) {

        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.data = data;
        mContext = context;       
    }    

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {    
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_card_row, parent, false);
        MyViewHolder viewHolder = new MyViewHolder(view);
        return viewHolder;
    }    

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        TimelineDataStore current = data.get(position);

        if (clickedPosition.equals("post")) {
            holder.postHeader.setText(current.postHeader);
            holder.postDescription.setText(current.postDescription);        
        }    
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {    
        return data.size();
    }

    public void setClickListener(ClickListener clickListener) {
        this.clickListener = clickListener;
    }

    public void setClickListener1(SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener clickListener1) {
        this.clickListener1 = clickListener1;
    }

    @Override
    public void itemClicked(View view, int position) {

    }    

    // View Holder object for Recycler View
    class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener, SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener, ToadlineCommentAdapter.ClickListener {

        TextView postHeader, postDescription;          

 public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            itemView.setOnClickListener((View.OnClickListener) this);
            postHeader = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewTitle);
            postDescription = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewPostDescription);
            mCardView = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_view);
            mShowMore = (ImageButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.buttonSeeMore);
            mShowLess = (ImageButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.buttonSeeLess);     

            mShowMore.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {    
                    int clickedPosition = getAdapterPosition();
                    TimelineDataStore current = data.get(clickedPosition);

                    current.postDescription = data.get(clickedPosition).postDescription;

                    postDescription.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    pollPostImages.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    mShowMore.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    mShowLess.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);         
                }    
            });    

            mShowLess.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {    
                    postDescription.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    pollPostImages.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    mShowMore.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    mShowLess.setVisibility(View.GONE);    
                }    
            });
}
```

Comment: How are we supposed to help you, if we don't know how you are expanding your cards..? :/ Also, by "selected" you mean clicked, activated, focused..?

Comment: It's due to recycling of views in ListView / RecyclerView. See Answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34597991/android-listview-with-toggle-button/34659646#34659646

Comment: @Keshav1234 Show the adapter code.

Comment: @KNeerajLal My Adapter code is too big. I will update the post with required code.

Comment: I meant the non-clicked Cards, which are "selected automatically".

Comment: @Amy means if i don click them they will seem to be clicked.

Comment: I have updated psot with my adapter code

Comment: @Desdroid Ur answer exactly answers my problem. I don have get view method. how can I adapt it. Can you please explain.

Comment: The getView method is due to List View. The equivalent for this Method in RecyclerViewAdapter is the onBindViewHolder method. Here you check if this position should be selected or not.

Comment: @Keshav1234 Do you have been able to solve the problem with my answer on the other thread? Or do you need further assistance/ explanation ?

Comment: @Desdroid Thanks for the link. I used a different way to solve the problem. Finally its resolved. Ur idea helped me think of another method.

Answer (score 0):

Every row has the same `OnClickListener`, since you set it in the `ViewHolder` class. 
One way to achieve your wanted behaviour would be to set the `OnClickListener` in the `OnBindViewHolder` method:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    TimelineDataStore current = data.get(position);

        holder.mShowMore.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                int clickedPosition = getAdapterPosition();
                TimelineDataStore current = data.get(clickedPosition);

                current.postDescription = data.get(clickedPosition).postDescription;

                postDescription.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                pollPostImages.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                mShowMore.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                mShowLess.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);     
            }
            holder.mShowLess.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                postDescription.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                pollPostImages.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                mShowMore.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                mShowLess.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            }


}
```

Comment: Then try the linked answer in the comments, from Desdroid.