# Right way to save String and Drawable resources in sqlite?

Tags: android, string, sqlite, drawable

I have Spinner or ListView with flag icon and currency name (I save their *R* ids in sqlite, for example *R.drawable.aed* and *R.string.aed* from drawable folder and *string.xml*)

Then I insert new drawable, for example cxx.png

My flag icons shifts, some of them changes with other images, not flags icons. This happen if I update app on my phone. If I install it, or delete and then install all work fine.

I understood, that sqlite in my program save *R* Ids of drawables only once on install. When I add or delete drawables or strings, *R* changes ids numbers, but in my sqlite table saved old *R* ids.

I can try to write method, that will update all *R* ids in sqlite everytime when I will add or delete new strings and drawables, by increasing DB_VERSION each time.
Is there simpler solution?

This is one of my Adapters:

```
public class SpinnerCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

public SpinnerCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    super(context, cursor, 0);
}

@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.spinner_item, parent, false);
    ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(view);
    view.setTag(viewHolder);
    return view;
}

@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    ViewHolder viewHolder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();

    int flagIconId = Integer.valueOf(cursor.getString(5));
    viewHolder.flagIcon.setImageResource(flagIconId);

    String currencyName = cursor.getString(4);
    viewHolder.currencyName.setText(currencyName);

    viewHolder.currencyCharCode.setText(cursor.getString(1));
}

private static class ViewHolder {
    final ImageView flagIcon;
    final TextView currencyName;
    final TextView currencyCharCode;

    private ViewHolder(View view) {
        flagIcon = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.spinner_flag_icon);
        currencyName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.spinner_currency_name);
        currencyCharCode = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.spinner_currency_char_code);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Yes you are right go ahead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find flexible solution for saving String and Drawable resources:
for example I have *blabla.png* and it's identifier *R.drawable.blabla*,
then I save String *blabla* in sqlite.

In my CursorAdapter I take current identifier of *blabla* using this:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4428288/318460

but instead of *Drawable.class* I use *R.drawable.class*.

Same with String resources.

Profit - it allows to change texts of strings in *string.xml* without updating sqlite table.

Answer (score 0):

For saving String from string.xml use :

```
context.getResources().getString(R.string.value);
```

and for saving Drawable id's use :

```
String.valueOf(R.drawable.aed)
```

So your query will be:

```
insertCurrency(db, CharCode.AED, 0, 1, 1, 0, 3.672950, 3.672950, context.getResources().getString(R.string.aed),String.valueOf(R.drawable.aed), 0, 1, 1);
```

Comment: I'll try this solution. What a difference between saving String - String.valueOf(R.drawable.aed) and just Integer - R.drawable.aed? I am afraid of that it doesn't solve problem - if I insert new image in drawable folder and update my app from google play, some images can shifts in ListView (ListView inflated by CursorAdapter from sqlite)

Comment: Image shifting is a [Recycling Problem of ListView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6921462/listview-reusing-views-when-i-dont-want-it-to) it is nothing to do with database and drawables & the Difference : I have converted the Int to **String** because by seeing your query **i guess your are entering String to the database so my guess was the column type of that column may be text or varchar**. If it is **Int** you can leave it **R.drawable.aed**

Comment: I have ViewHolder in Adapters.

Comment: still you need some ArrayList to maintain the exact position with TAGs..!!

Comment: My problem - for example I have 'apple', 'melon', 'pear' in ListView. Then I adding new String 'mmmm' in string.xml and update app on my phone - ViewList shifts items not all but since certain position, in than case shifts will be from 'm' char. But if I remove app and then install where is no problem.

Comment: i m not getting your problem will you please edit the question with some screenshots (before and after).. It would be more better.>!!

Comment: Ok, I'll make screenshots when problem repeats. And I'll try to add ArrayList to maintain the exact position with TAGs

Comment: I've updated the question with screenshots , please see

Comment: Its is the recycling view of listView problem. can i see your adapter code ?? @Polurival