# Android ListView FindViewById confusion

Tags: android, android-listview, listviewitem, findviewbyid

I had a Listview with the following Adapter

```
SimpleAdapter simpleAdapter
            = new SimpleAdapter(NewsListActivity.this,res,R.layout.newslist_adapter,new String[]{"title","description","link"},new int[]{R.id.title,R.id.description,R.id.url});    
            
            lView.setAdapter(simpleAdapter);
```

where **lView** is the ListView, and **res** is an HashMap.

In the ListView's onItemClick, I was able to get each View's Description TextView using the Code below

```
    @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) 
                {
                    
                    View v1 = lView.getChildAt(position - lView.getFirstVisiblePosition());
                    
                    if(v1 != null){
                    TextView des = v1.findViewById(R.id.description);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),des.getText(),0).show();       // returns the Text at exact TextView Clicked
                    des.setBackgroundColor(R.color.red);   //Here is the PROBLEM, It changes the Background Color of TextView I clicked on, but it ALSO changes some other TextView's background color
                    }
            }
```

As I added in the Comments, The Toast message returns The exact Text in the TextView, but changing the background color also changes some other TextView in the ListView's color

I don't seem to Understand what I am doing wrong.

**EDIT**

I only posted the portion of the project , so as not mess up all the place with my source code.

It's an RSS feed reader project, but now I realize the problem is with all ListViews. Pleased kindly help with the link below

[Android ListView getChild() not working properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65266929/android-listview-getchild-not-working-properly)

Comment: please post the row item layout of the `ListView`

Comment: The items are dynamically generated from RSS News from some Rss feed. Just normal key-valur pair in HashMap

Comment: **Edit**  I realized the Problem is with all ListViews.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65266929/android-listview-getchild-not-working-properly

Comment: I mean to share from which layout you get `R.id.description` can you share it?; maybe from `R.layout.newslist_adapter`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after months of confusion, pain of being self-taught and punishment of walking alone (no direct access to senior dev for help), I finally realized what I was missing.

The problem arise from ListView re-using view as some sort of memory management techniques (for performance purposes) or so. That's why in my case whenever the background color of a  ListView Element is changed and the View is being recycled it affect the background color of whichever item that uses the Recycled view.

As for the fix, this [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6921462/listview-reusing-views-when-i-dont-want-it-to) link should help